# Select values with two occurrences within a given time range

Tags: sql, where-clause, exists

I have dataset in GOOGLE CLOUD using STANDARD SQL with date, time and customerID visiting a store, where I wish to keep only those customerID's which are seen on on the same day, but only those between 06-09 (morning) and 14-16 (afternoon) oclock. So, only customers who were present BOTH in the morning and afternoon and not only EITHER morning or afternoon

```
customerID  Date       start_time

1234      01.10.2019    07:52:27
1234      01.10.2019    14:10:18
5678      01.10.2019    15:19:18
5678      01.10.2019    16:54:25
1011      02.10.2019    06:15:00
1011      02.10.2019    17:00:00
2222      02.10.2019    08:00:00
2222      02.10.2019    08:45:00
```

Output should be like this:

```
customerID  Date   start_time morning/afternoon

1234    01.10.2019  07:52:27  seen both morning and afternoon
1234    01.10.2019  14:10:18  seen both morning and afternoon
1011    02.10.2019  06:15:00  seen both morning and afternoon
1011    02.10.2019  17:00:00  seen both morning and afternoon
```

As you can see, only those with start_time both in the morning (between 06-09) and afternoon (between 14-17) is taken out. Dont need the last column (morning/afternoon) but just for demonstration. I am not sure how to achieve this and I have tried various AND/OR, WHERE, WHERE EXISTS but nowhere close. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: I have removed the <ansi-sql> tag because this is obviously not ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: no im so sorry , got recommended by the tag editor. I've removed this, and highlighted my database: Google Cloud using SQL and Bigquery. New to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to resolve using spark-sql. Please refer below the logic

1. Extract Hour from start_time and mark all customers visited in 06-09
   as 1 and 14-17 marked as -1 called new column visit_status
2. Create a group of customerID,date then sum(visit_status)
3. Select records for which sum(visit_status) = 0 these are the
   customers visited in morning and afternoon

```py
#Step 1
df_temp = spark.sql("""select customerID,Date, start_time,
case when EXTRACT(HOUR from start_time) between 6 and 9 then 1 
when EXTRACT(HOUR from start_time) between 14 and 17 then -1
else 10
end as visit_status from customers""")

#Step 2
df_temp.registerTempTable("temp")
new_df = spark.sql("""select customerID,
Date, start_time, 
sum(visit_status) 
over( partition by customerID,Date) as final_status from temp""")

#Step 3 filter record for which sum = 0 
new_df = new_df.filter("final_status = 0")
new_df = new_df.withColumn("final_status", when(new_df['final_status'] == 0, "seen both morning and afternoon"))
new_df.show(10,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest version returns a single row per customer:

```
select
   customerID
  ,Date
  ,min(start_time)
  ,max(start_time)
from tab
-- no time before 6 and after 16 
where start_time between time '06:00:00' and time '16:00:00'
-- to filter exactly
-- where start_time between time '06:00:00' and time '09:00:00'
--    or start_time between time '14:00:00' and time '16:00:00'
group by
   customerID
  ,Date
having min(start_time) <= time '09:00:00' -- at least one row between  6 and  9
   and max(start_time) >= time '14:00:00' -- at least one row between 14 and 16
```

If you really need both rows you can apply the same logic using *Windowed Aggregates* like this:

```
with cte as
 (
    select
       customerID
      ,Date
      ,min(start_time)
      ,count(*) over (partition by customerI, Date) as cnt
    from tab
    where start_time between time '06:00:00' and time '09:00:00'
       or start_time between time '14:00:00' and time '16:00:00'
    group by
       customerID
      ,Date
      ,case when start_time between time '06:00:00' and time '09:00:00' then 1
            when start_time between time '14:00:00' and time '16:00:00' then 2
       end
 )
select * 
from cte 
where cnt = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
SELECT a.customerid,
       a.date,
       MIN(a.start_time) AS am_start,
       MIN(b.start_time) AS pm_start
FROM   t1 a
       JOIN t1 b
         ON a.customerid = b.customerid
            AND a.date = b.date
            AND a.start_time BETWEEN TIME '06:00:00' AND TIME '09:00:00'
            AND b.start_time BETWEEN TIME '14:00:00' AND TIME '16:00:00'
GROUP BY  a.customerid, a.t1date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*,
        count(*) filter(where start_time <= '09:00:00') over(partition by customerid, date) cnt_morning,
        count(*) filter(where start_time >= '15:00:00') over(partition by customerid, date) cnt_afternoon,
    from mytable t
    where start_time between '06:00:00' and '09:00:00' 
       or start_time between '15:00:00' and '19:00:00' 
) t
where cnt_morning > 0 and cnt_afternoon > 0
```

The subquery filters on the two time ranges you are intersted in, and use window counts to compute the number of occurences of each customer within each range on a daily basis. The outer query then just filters on the counts.

You did not tell which database you are running, and you tagged you question `ansi-sql`, so this uses the standard `filter` clause on window functions. A more portable way to phrase this is:

```
        sum(case when start_time <= '09:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by customerid, date) cnt_morning,
        sum(case when start_time >= '15:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by customerid, date) cnt_afternoon,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.start_time between '06:00:00' and '09:00:00' and
       exists (select 1
               from t t2
               where t2.customerid = t.customerid and
                     t2.date = t.date and
                     t2.start_time between '14:00:00' and '16:00:00'
              )
      ) or
      (t.start_time between '14:00:00' and '16:00:00' and
       exists (select 1
               from t t2
               where t2.customerid = t.customerid and
                     t2.date = t.date and
                     t2.start_time between '06:00:00' and '09:00:00'
              )
      );
```

I did not include the last column `seen both morning and afternoon`.  That seems superfluous.

I'm not 100% sure that the time frame are exactly what you want.  You could mean any of the following for morning, for instance:

```
start_time >= '06:00:00' and start_time < '09:00:00'
start_time >= '06:00:00' and start_time <= '09:00:00'
start_time >= '06:00:00' and start_time < '10:00:00'
start_time >= '06:00:00' and start_time <= '10:00:00'
```

Based on your sample data, you want the last (although I would not be my first interpretation of the question).  But that seems like a small detail.

I suggest this approach for two reasons:

- It keeps all the original rows, even if there are multiple rows in the morning and afternoon.  That seems to be the intent of your question, although I personally would prefer just one row per customer.
- With an index on `(customerid, date, start_time)`, it should have very good performance.